# Adding pastevalue and timestamp in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I having been trying to add paste value command because all the value that I copy are average data column and I need a timestamp in the row1 of every time I click the button. No matter what method I try its leading me no where. So can you please help me.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Input")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2")

'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

If destination.Cells(1, 1) = "" And emptyColumn = 2 Then emptyColumn = 1

source.Range("s1:s35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need the last empty column, please, replace `If destination.Cells(1, 1) = "" And emptyColumn = 2 Then emptyColumn = 1` with `If destination.cells(1, 1) <> "" And emptyColumn = 1 Then emptyColumn = 2`...

Comment: I have a employee performance excel sheet where the employee updates their activities and I have calculated the average, so I am planning to copy the average to the another sheet so that I can generate a time chart. so if i click a button i need the average column to get copied and the column first row should have the month followed by the average values and if click the button next time it should reflect that month followed by the copied values to the next blank column. since its average if copy i'm getting #REF! so I need the pastevalue command to work. Thanks

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested above?

Comment: Are there formulae in the range you try copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code to find the first unused column, as I'm sure you've realised. I think your question is purely about writing *values*.

If you just want the values without the formulae, then you can just write the values without copy/paste:

Instead of:

```
source.Range("s1:s35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)
```

Use:

```
destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn).Resize(35, 1).Value = source.Range("s1:s35").Value
```

The part you might not recognise is broken down as follows:

```
destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn  ' this is the first cell of the target

.Resize(35, 1)                    ' this resizes the above cell to a range 1x35 as per source
```

---

UPDATE:

Here is a copy of the full proc with an improved method to find first available column.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim emptyColumn As Long
    
    Set source = Sheets("Input")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' if there is nothing in the first column then
    ' set emptyColumn to first column
    ' otherwise, find last used column and add 1

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(destination.Columns(1)) Then
        emptyColumn = 1
    Else
        emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    End If

    ' copy value contents of cells to identical sized range

    destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn).Resize(35, 1).Value = source.Range("s1:s35").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you the code works but if I click the button again its not copying the values again  in the next column. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Does the first cell in your source column (S1) contain data? Because if not, the test you put to check if the sheet is blank will mean it will keep overwriting the first column.

Comment: I've modified my answer to now include an improved method of checking the first column.